# Location Services not working in background called by WatchKit

Tags: ios, background, watchkit, location-services

My Apple Watch app requires some data and requests it from the corresponding iPhone app. To fulfill the request the iPhone app requires the users location. 
After receiving and testing with a real Apple Watch I found out that my iPhone app does not receive location updates when running in background. If the iPhone app is active in foreground it works without issues. With the simulator it worked in both cases.

In both cases (active and background) the WatchKit extension calls and starts successfully the iPhone app and goes all the way until startUpdatingLocation is called in the iPhone app. But in case the app is running in background didUpdateLocations is never called.

I tried with requestAlwaysAuthorization as well as requestWhenInUseAuthorization. No difference.
I also activated then the "location updates" background mode within capabilities. But again no difference.

Has someone else faced the same problem and found a way to receive the location also in background?

Here some code. First the check if authorization is required.

```
// iOS 8 check to avoid crash on older iOS
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self requestLocationAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    else
    {
        [self runLocationUpdate];
    }
```

Here the check for the proper Location Manager rights.

```
- (void)requestLocationAlwaysAuthorization
{
CLAuthorizationStatus currentAuthStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (currentAuthStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    //request user to change setting
}
else if (currentAuthStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
{
    //request user to change setting
}
else if (currentAuthStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    [self runLocationUpdate];
}
else if (currentAuthStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
{
    //maybe when in use is also enough?
    [self runLocationUpdate];
}
else if (currentAuthStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
{
    //all ok
    [self runLocationUpdate];
}
```

}

Here the call of startUpdatingLocation. The didUpdateLocations delegate will only be called when iPhone app is active.

```
-(void)runLocationUpdate
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?  Depending on when and how you asked for requestAlwaysAuthorization could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I added some code. The problem is also there when requestAlwaysAuthorization is not called because setting is already as required on always. The call of requestAlwaysAuthorization results in a proper change in iPhone privacy settings.

Comment: Btw, it seems that the kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways is not necessary anymore when the iPhone app runs in background mode. The status kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse is enough now.

Comment: Careful, unless you are calling the location manager from the watch app extension, it has been my experience that "while in use" permission does not work if the app in not in the foreground . It does work on the simulator but not on a real watch.

Comment: Here the latest update after the belonging app is successfully working with real devices and available in the app store: The requestWhenInUseAuthorization is enough, the iPhone app is handled as in foreground when called from the Watch even when in background. Also there is no need for any background mode. The only thing required is the use of a background task as explained by rmp here in the solution. Thanks again to rmp!

Comment: Awesome congrats on getting your app into the store!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things to check and be aware of:

1. Location Permissions like `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` are only acknowledged once by the OS. If you have already requested permission, doesn't matter the level, the OS will NOT display a request to the user. The OS will just pass over the request and leave the permission level as is.  The only time you can be assured that the OS will display the request to the user is if the  `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` returns `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`.  In every other case, you must manually request permission by displaying an Alert or other form of UI display. Also note that the OS retains whether or not it already displayed the request, even if you delete your app and reinstall it. So to test, you need to reset your Simulator's Content or your iPhone's Location Privacy.
2. Make sure you have added the plist keys for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` AND `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` If you don't add this to your plist, the OS will ignore any Location Permission Requests.
3. If you want to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` to get location data from the phone (not the watch app extension) while the phone app is in the background, will also require you register for Background Modes Location updates under Project>Target>Capabilities.

**UPDATE**
Use a background task to give your app time to respond when in the background. Something like this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply{

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask __block = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"watchAppRequest" expirationHandler:^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];

//make your calls here to your tasks, when finished, send the reply then terminate the background task

//send reply back to watch
reply(replyInfo);

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Comment: My experience so for regarding the mentioned three topics: 1.) I use UIAlertController to inform the user and open the settings dialog if the user likes by using UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString 2.) Exactly, I have both strings and find the two settings "when in use" and "always" also in the iPhone settings app. 3.) Correct, as mentioned I did that also. The first two were also necessary to get it running in the simulator. But it is still not working on the real Watch device when the iPhone app is in the background

Comment: By chance are you using other services or technology that needs background access?  Do you use a keychain for authentication?

Comment: Also, is this functionality wrapped in a `BackgroundTask`?

Comment: After I receive the users location the app calls a server to get the required data. Therefore I also set the "Background fetch" mode of the Background capabilities. But as didUpdateLocations is not called when the iPhone app is in background the app is not calling the server. No issue when iPhone app is active. The keychain is not used in the app.

Comment: What about using a `BackgroundTask`? Are your calls wrapped in a `BackgroundTask` to allow that app time to respond when in the background?

Comment: You are saying that startUpdatingLocation and/or didUpdateLocations should be somehow wrapped in a Background task?

Comment: Thanks a lot, background tasks seems to be the way to go. The app received the location now also when the iPhone app is in background.